# How to define and process the opposite of a long list argument in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How to define and process the opposite of a long list argument in bash ?

Answer (score 4):

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) you can do it with [Arithmetic Expansion](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html) if you only have arithmetical conditions:

```
#!/bin/bash

var4=10
var1=9
var3=2
var2=1

# Arithmetic Expansion:
# set condition to 1 if it's true or 0 if it's not
condition=$(( var4 < var1 || var3 > var2 ))

# !=  is  "not equal to"
if [[ $condition != 1 ]]; then
    echo "! cond"
else
    echo "cond"
fi
```

The condition testing could also be done like this:

```
if ! ((condition)); then
```

where `!` stands for `not`

Comment: Thank you, why it is setting the condition to 1 and how do you know it ? Also, I thought in bash we couldn't use ">" "<" but "lt" "gt" instead, isn't that true ?

Comment: @linuxuser The 1 or 0 is the boolean result of the condition testing inside the arithmetic expansion. Use the `if [[ conditions... ]]` testing in [tag:bash]. It's much more versatile than the [tag:sh] `if [ conditions ... ]` - so `if [[ 1 > 2 ]]` evaluates to `false` but `if [ 1 > 2 ]` (tries to) create a file named `2` in `#!/bin/sh` and most likely evaluates to `true`...

Comment: Since you are using arithmetic expansion, `if ((condition)); then ...` is probably more readable since "condition" is akin to a boolean here.

Comment: @xhienne Good catch! Added alternative.

Comment: Like this ?
condition=$(("$var4" -lt "$var2" -o "$var3" -gt "$var2" )) , next line, 
if ! [ ((condition)) ]; then  ,is this correct ?

Comment: @linuxuser Not quite. Use  `<` instead of `-lt`,  `>` instead of `-gt`, `||` instead of `-o` and `&&` instead of `-a` for boolean expressions inside `$(( ...  ))`. It's similar to when testing numbers in `[[ ... ]]`. If you have `bash` then use its powers. The code will be safer and more readable.

Comment: Are we allowed to use "<" and ">" inside if [ ]  to compare numbers ? I thought only -lt and -gt and so on. I still don't understand why your condition is sending 1. Why 1 ? What is 1 ? Why not 2, 3 ?

Comment: @linuxuser No, not when testing inside `if [ ]` but when testing inside `if [[ ]]`. The first is an actual command called `test` (`[` is usually a hard link to that command). The second is a `bash` built-in (with a lot more safety and capabilities). Returning `1` for `true` and `0`  for `false` is standard by convention in [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).

Comment: @Ted `<` and `>` can be used inside `[...]` and `[[...]]` but in *both* cases they deal with strings, not integer and thus must be avoided here as they may return a wrong result (e.g. `[ -2 "<" -3 ]` or `[[ -2 < -3 ]]` would yield a true-ish value)

Comment: Sorry to interrupt but what is the difference between [ ] and [ [  ] ] ?

Comment: `[` is a command called [`test`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/testh.html) that gets executed. You can write `if test -r "$file"` or `if [ -r "$file" ]` to check if a file is readable. They do the same thing. `[[` is built into the `bash` language. It doesn't require `"` around variables etc and allows for comparisons with `<` etc.

Answer (score 2):

In Bourne shell `[` is a command (see with `type [`). Actually it's another name for the `test` command.

Let's take your example:

```
if [ "$var4" -lt "$var1" ]; then ...; fi
```

(`$` were added by me since those are variables)

> But what if I have many conditions...

The `test` and `[` commands accept an arbitrary list of conditions:

```
if [ "$var4" -lt "$var1" -o "$var3" -gt "$var2" ]; then ...; fi
```

(`-o` is a logical OR)

> ... and would like to take the opposite of the result of all of them like

Like *any* command in Bourne shell, you can test for the opposite outcome (command did not return OK) with the `!` sign:

```
if ! [ "$var4" -lt "$var1" -o "$var3" -gt "$var2" ]; then ...; fi
```

Alternatively, the `test` and `[` commands also have a NOT operator (written `!`):

```
if [ ! '(' "$var4" -lt "$var1" -o "$var3" -gt "$var2" ')' ]; then ...; fi
```

(you have to use parentheses here since you want to negate the whole compound expression)

Further readings with `man test` and `help test`.

Of course, you can do it in two steps like this:

```
[ "$var4" -lt "$var1" -o "$var3" -gt "$var2" ]
condition=$?
# Now condition contains the result of the [ command,
# which is 0 if it the test is true and 1 otherwise
if [ "$condition" -ne 0 ]; then ...
```

Admittedly, the `[ "$condition" -ne 0 ]` syntax is counter-intuitive and less readable; one may prefer Ted Lyngmo's answer instead.

Another more readable alternative:

```
condition=false
[ "$var4" -lt "$var1" -o "$var3" -gt "$var2" ] && condition=true
# "true" and "false" being two Unix commands,
# we can now use condition like this:
if ! "$condition"; then ...
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Is there a way to isolate all conditions in a variable like python ? In the example the list is short, but there are other cases where the list is long

Comment: You can execute the `[` command without the `if` and retrieve `$?` which contains its exit status. `[ ! '(' "$var4" -lt  ... ]; condition=$?` (beware: $?=0 means that the command executed successfully and that the condition is true). Ted Lyngmo's answer is probably more readable.

Comment: I mean, defining the condition before the if and using it inside the if. like the python syntax if not (condition).

Comment: I did understand what you asked for but my comment wasn't clear enough. I have amended my answer instead of replying here. I deliberately didn't use arithmetic expansion in order to stick with your example that used the `[` command. If you prefer arithmetic expansion, see Ted Lyngmo's answer.

Comment: @linuxuser You are mixing [tag:shell]s. They are similar - but still different. You should probably remove the [tag:shell] tag and one of the other tags. If you prefer Bourne shell over [tag:bash] (like I suspect) I'll delete my answer and upvote this instead.

Comment: @linuxuser Another pure Bourne shell alternative added to my answer

Comment: What do you mean by mixing shells ? I am using bash (#!/bin/bash)

Comment: @linuxuser `bash` is a superset of the original Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`). It offers more functionalities. For example `[[` does not exist in the original Bourne shell.

Comment: @linuxuser "_What do you mean by mixing shells_" - You use invalid syntax in `bash` features like arithmetic expansion. `$(( 1 -lt 2 ))` is a syntax error while `$(( 1 < 2 ))` evaluates to `1` (for `true`).

Answer (score 1):

Since you specify `bash`, you can do it arithmetically -

```
if (( var4 < var1 )) || (( var3 > var2 )); then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

or all at a go --

```
if [[ "$var4" -lt "$var1" || "$var3" -gt "$var2" ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

If you use the latter, `<` and `>` evaluate their args as strings and compare them by lexigraphic sorting, which should be LOCALE specific.

c.f. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html

To get the "not" of a condition, predicate with `!`.
To get a *compound* condition as a unit you can collectively invert with that *not*, enclose in parens.

```
if [[ ! ( "$var4" -lt "$var1" || "$var3" -gt "$var2" ) ]]; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

As for your question - *" is there a way to do like python, defining a variable for big list of conditions and doing a not on that condition ?"* - I suspect your assumption is imprecise. Python does not put all the compound conditions in the variable, it *evaluates* them and saves the boolean **result**, which the `if` then parses, and can negate.

It sounds like what you want to do is set up a series of tests, save the boolean, then get the reverse of *that*. In `bash`, if that's just the structure you want, I'd do something like this -

```
[[ ( "$var4" -lt "$var1" || "$var3" -gt "$var2" ) ]]; # set return code
if (( $? )) ...                                       # check as math
```

The *true* return from a normal conditional is a zero (`0`), which evaluates to `false` in arithmetic context. Any other response (nonzero) evaluates as boolean false in a normal `[[...]]` return code, but `true` in arithmetic context, so evaluating `$?` in an arithmetic context you are implicitly applying a "*not*".

You can add a step between to save `$?` to another variable, but the result is the same. Just remember that any time you do this, you are flipping from return code testing to arithmetic testing, so it ALWAYS adds the *not* implicitly. That's a documentation and maintenance nightmare. I strongly recommend *against* it for that reason.